# AngualarJS $anchorScroll Service does DOM manipulation

Tags: angularjs, dom, service

I have started using AngularJS and recently I came across using `$anchorScroll` service provided by AngularJS. It works perfectly fine. However when I peered into their code I was confused to see DOM manipulation which is used to adjust scrollbar. As AngularJS always says write DOM manipulations only in directives why Core AngularJS doesn't follow this? I mean, at least in case of `$anchorScroll`?

I don't understand whether it's allowed to manipulate DOM in our services or not? If not why AngularJS itself takes an exception?

Comment: DOM manipulation in services are acceptable pattern depending upon what that service is for. It is a common pattern in many other libraries like ui bootstrap, router etc.. But it is a bad practise when you do DOM manipulation on the controller.

Comment: Circumstantially, there is no issue with it. but when considering DOM manipulation in the general use of angular, you should consider the best ways it is set up to do DOM manipulation - mostly directives.